# I can't install packages in R either by using devtools or directly from tar.gz file

Tags: r, installation, package, repository

Recently, I have been having trouble to install packages that are not currently listed in CRAN, either by downloading it directly from the github page using devtools or by using a tar.gz file. I always get the same error, which is something is these lines:

```
    Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
    (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
    * installing *source* package 'rbcb' ...
    ** package 'rbcb' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
    cannot open file 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win- 
    library/3.5/rbcb/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory
    Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
    cannot open the connection
    ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'rbcb'
    * removing 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rbcb'
    In R CMD INSTALL
    Warning message:
    In install.packages("C:/Users/Downloads/rbcb_0.1.5.tar.gz",  :
    installation of package ‘C:/Users/Downloads/rbcb_0.1.5.tar.gz’ had non- 
    zero exit status
```

When using devtools I get a similar error

```
    devtools::install_github('wilsonfreitas/rbcb')
    Downloading GitHub repo wilsonfreitas/rbcb@master
    from URL https://api.github.com/repos/wilsonfreitas/rbcb/zipball/master
    Installing rbcb
    "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  
    \--no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \  



  "C:/Users/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpYXAtfa/devtools1e702535224f/wilsonfreitas-rbcb-b70fb09"  \
  --library="C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.5" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'rbcb' ...
Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rbcb/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
  cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'rbcb'
* removing 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rbcb'
In R CMD INSTALL
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

Comment: "by using a tar.gz file" How exactly are you doing this? Does it work with `install.packages`? What code are you using? `'C:/Users/Documents/R/win- 
    library/3.5/rbcb/DESCRIPTION'` looks unusual. There should be a user name after `Users/` in the file path.

Comment: There is. I ommited, that's all. I'm using the command install.packages("C:/Users/André/Downloads/rbcb_0.1.5.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")

Comment: I'm not sure this is the issue, but just to remove all possibilities, have you installed Rtools?

Comment: Yes, I did install it a while ago when I were trying to install another package, and that’s when I first got this error. I thought that it was a admin rigths situation, because a while back I had to format my notebook and the new windows installation was all messed up. But even when I run RStudio with admin rights I get this error. And just to be clear, I do not have any troubke installing packages through Cran repositories.